# Vaadin + GWT-Graphics

Tags: gwt, vaadin

I am trying to integrate Vaadin and GWT-Graphics. Already read everything I could find in the web but still no result

I need to draw circles linked with lines. Those objects should handle right-clicks... So I think I need to have different Vaadin wrappers for GWT-Graphics like DrawingArea, Circle etc

Also it is not clear for me what object should I extend to implement server-side Vaadin object for DrawingArea?
 DrawingArea has parameters in constructor: width and height, how should I handle it in server-side Vaadin object?

Maybe you have seen some examples or sample codes for GWT-Graphics in Vaadin or have some experience with it?

I'm really stuck on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Henri, who's created GWT-Graphics, also made some sample Vaadin chart components using GWT-Graphics. Check out the [components](http://hene.virtuallypreinstalled.com/Charts) and their [source](http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/incubator/ChartsWithGWTGraphics). These are also mentioned in the [forum post](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/72143) about GWT-Graphics.

Comment: Yep, I saw it but I have to handle right click on my components... you know I want to draw something like UML diagram with ability to have a context menu on each class in this diagram. AFAIK GWT doesnt provide this ability just out-of-the-box. I was seeking for workaround but failed to find any. Thats was one of the reason i chose Vaadin framework. I see workaround: I can draw lines with GWT-Graphics and place regular Vaadin Image components over those lines... Can you see better solution?